# Require array lenght no working

Tags: dapps, arrays, require

I have the following function

```
function mint(uint256[] memory tokens) public payable {
        require(saleIsActive, "Sale is not active");
        require(tokens.length == 0, "No tokens to mint");
    require(
        tokens.length > maxGradisPurchase,
        "number of tokens incorrect"
    );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, tokens[i]);
            _setTokenURI(tokens[i], "sometokeuri");
            _totalTokens.increment();
        }

}
```

but the `require(tokens.length == 0, "No tokens to mint");` is not working, here is my javascript test:

```
it('should not allow to mint a gradis if token array is empty', async () => {
    // activate sales before test
    await myContractInstance.flipSaleState({ from: accounts[0] });

    const tokensToMint = [1];
    await myContractInstance.flipSaleState
      .mint(tokensToMint, {
        from: accounts[1],
        value: 1000000000000000,
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        assert(
          error.message,
          'Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Sale is not active -- Reason given: Token is not correct.'
        );
      });

    const minted = await gradisInstance.totalSupply();
  });
```

but the require is always triggered and I don't understand why the Code alway have a `token.length`equal to zero even though I am recibing the correct token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the require is not working and tokens are getting minted, but that is as expected: `require(condition, revertString)` means that if the condition is *false*, then the transaction will revert.

In your case, since you pass to the function parameters that satisfy the condition (tokens list of length either 0 or 6), the require does not trigger and the tokens are minted as you described.

If you want to test that it's working, pass only 4 items to it: `const tokensToMint = [1, 2, 3, 4]`. Then the transaction should revert with your `"Token is not correct"` message.

Comment: Thank you so much I Just update my Code, but as you can see my Problem is that the array variable length is always cero even though I have data inside the array

Comment: You're welcome, it's the same problem now mate :) You should use require the opposite way - change it to `require(tokens.length > 0, "No tokens to mint");`. This means if tokens.length is _not_ > 0, then the tx will revert.